# How to avoid dragging the parent when dragging it's child?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draggable

I've added to my `React` app navigation bar which the user can drag items and replace positions. (Works fine!)

Now I'm trying to render recursively the navigation tree, so inner navigations can be dragged and replaced (no reparenting).

Rendering recursively works fine, but the problem is dragging an inner child causes dragging the whole parent node.

`NodeWrapper.js`:

```
export class NodeWrapper extends Component {
  public render() {
    return (
      <DragList onItemMoved={this.props.onItemMoved}>
        {this.props.navItems
          .map((component, index) => (
            <Node key={`node-${index}`} {...component}/>
          ))}
      </DragList>
    );
  }
}
```

`Node.js`:

```
public render() {
 return (
  <div>
    <span>{this.props.label}</span>
    {this.props.childNodes && (
      <NodeWrapper navItems={this.props.childNodes} />
    )}
  </div>
 );
}
```

*Note, the `DragList` component is really huge, and I don't think that it's relevant to the question, will add if asked. Basically it renders a list of children with ability to drag them with event handler.

I've tried to add `event.stopPropagation()` for the drag event handler, but it still captures and drags the whole parent node.

How can I perform drag between all levels?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to make a small, e.g. codesandbox project that we could play around with? I don't think this can be answered like it currently stands and I bet nobody wants to spend time and build a working demo first.

Comment: Can you show the documentation for `DragList`. Html elements have `draggable` attribute that can be set to `false` to disable dragging.

Comment: event.stopPropagation seems to be the way to go but how and where you use it could be the key for the solution to work. Could you please add DragList code to check it?

Answer (score 0):

on inner child element on every eventl listener you want like onDrag and onClick use e.stopPropagation()

for example

```
<div class="wraper">
  <div class="inner" onDrag={(e)=>{e.stopPropagation();//do other sttuf}}></div>
</div>
```

just use event.stopPropagation() inside inner child  event handler of drag,... event listener

i can not see your implementation to figure out how you use drag events.but i'm gussing that you use  onItemMoved prop and pass it's value to drag handler so
try this

```
onItemMoved={(e)=> {e.stopPropagation();this.props.onItemMoved()}}
```

Answer (score 0):

To enable dragging at all levels of your navigation tree without affecting the entire parent node, you should consider implementing a recursive drag-and-drop mechanism. You're on the right track with `event.stopPropagation()`, but it's important to use it effectively.

Here's a modified version of your code that handles dragging at all levels within your navigation tree:

NodeWrapper.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import DragList from "./DragList"; // Import your DragList component

class NodeWrapper extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <DragList onItemMoved={this.props.onItemMoved}>
        {this.props.navItems.map((component, index) => (
          <Node key={`node-${index}`} {...component} />
        )}
      </DragList>
    );
  }
}

export default NodeWrapper;
```

Node.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Node extends Component {
  onDragStart = (e) => {
    // Use the onDragStart event to prevent dragging propagation
    e.stopPropagation();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span
          draggable={true}
          onDragStart={this.onDragStart}
        >
          {this.props.label}
        </span>
        {this.props.childNodes && (
          <NodeWrapper navItems={this.props.childNodes} onItemMoved={this.props.onItemMoved} />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Node;
```

Key points to note:

1. In the `Node` component, we've added a `draggable` attribute to the `<span>` element, which makes it draggable.
2. We've added an `onDragStart` event handler to the `<span>` element. This event handler prevents the drag event from propagating further up the DOM tree, effectively stopping the dragging from affecting the entire parent node.
3. When rendering child nodes using `NodeWrapper`, we pass the `onItemMoved` function down so that the drag-and-drop functionality is available at all levels.

With this approach, you should be able to drag elements at any level within your navigation tree without affecting the entire parent node.