# How can I prevent dragging the whole carousel when the user wants to drag the Slider (React Mantine)

Tags: reactjs, frontend, mantine

I am creating an app and I need to use **Mantine Carousel** for that. There will some inputs in the carousel and the user can check all slides one by one and fill them by order. But when I am using Mantine Slider in the carousel there is a problem.

Whenever the user drags the Slider input in the Carousel, the whole carousel drags with the Slider input. I can imagine it is a bit confusing when I am trying to explain it, but I think you understand what I am saying.

You can find the example code below:

```
import { Carousel } from "@mantine/carousel";
import { Slider, Text } from "@mantine/core";

export default function TestPage() {
  return (
    <Carousel
      withIndicators
      slideGap="xl"
      align="center"
      dragFree
      slidesToScroll={1}
      slideSize={"50%"}
      p={100}
    >
      <Carousel.Slide p={"xl"}>
        <Text>Slider 1</Text>
        <Slider></Slider>
      </Carousel.Slide>
    </Carousel>
  );
}
```

I tried to use event.stopPropogation() in onPointerDown() listener. Put it in the Slider and then Carousel.Slide but none of them worked.

Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56528655/how-to-avoid-dragging-the-parent-when-dragging-its-child) but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly this is the solution which you tried to achieve:

```html
<Carousel
  withIndicators
  slideGap="xl"
  align="center"
  dragFree
  slidesToScroll={1}
  slideSize={"50%"}
  p={10>
   <Carousel.Slide p={"xl"}>
     <TextInput
       label="Input label"
       description="Input description"
       placeholder="Input placeholder"
     />
   </Carousel.Slide>
   <Carousel.Slide p={"xl"}>
     <TextInput
       label="Input label"
       description="Input description"
       placeholder="Input placeholder"
     />
   </Carousel.Slide>
</Carousel>
```

For each slide on your carousel you can add <Carousel.Slide>. Carousel.Slide also accepts childs so I added TextInput. Dont forget to import TextInput from mantine/core.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).